Derive the posterior multivariate normal distribution
I have a question when I was reading the book Latent Variable Models and Factor Analysis: A Unified Approach by Bartholomew, Knott and Moustaki. Here it is:
Suppose that $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_p)^T$, in which all $x$s are random variables, and $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\boldsymbol \mu, \boldsymbol \Sigma)$.
Also, $\mathbf{y}$ is a set of $q$ latent variables and $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}_q(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$.
Finally, we also have
$\mathbf{x|y} \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\boldsymbol{\mu+\Lambda y}, \boldsymbol{\Psi})$, where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is a p*q matrix and $\boldsymbol{\Psi}$ is a diagonal matrix of variances.
I know by iterated expectation and iterated variance formulas one can easily get another way to express the distribution of $\mathbf{x}$, which turns out to be $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}_p(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Lambda \Lambda^{'}+\Psi})$.
But I don't know how can I reach the posterior distribution below:
$\mathbf{y|x} \sim \mathcal{N}_q(\boldsymbol{\Lambda^{'}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}, (\boldsymbol{\Lambda^{'}\Psi^{-1}\Lambda + I})^{-1})$.
I have tried the Bayes formula:
$f(y|x)=\frac{f(x|y)f(y)}{f(x)}$ but I wasn't optimistic of the calculation after substitutions...
Can anyone help me to reach that posterior distribution? Thank you!

The calculation is gnarly, but here is a way to simplify it.
Consider the ensemble of multivariate Gaussians. Normally, you parameterize it using the mean and covariance. However, this is really inconvenient for this particular calculation.
Instead, observe that you can parameterize Gaussians instead with their inverse covariance and $\Sigma^-1 \mu$. These are the coefficients of the second degree polynomial that defines the log-probability of the Gaussian.
Now, with that parameterization, the calculations simplify and I encourage you to do them. The reason why is because the Gaussians are an exponential family and this other parameterization is their natural parameterization. The natural parameterization leads to convenient calculations for likelihoods, and when combined with a conjugate prior, to convient calculations of the posterior distribution.
NB: your model is weird. You have both defined the marginal distribution of $x$ and of the pair $y, x|y$.
